# How to migrate a git repo to a new laptop

Tags: git

I am new to git, so bear with me.

I have a laptop, we will call it A and a new laptop, we will call it B.
Now A is an old laptop and is failing.

I want to move my git repo from A to B so I can keep working on that repo from B and delete repo from A (because A is barely functioning anymore).

I need steps on how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start a git repo, a hidden folder `.git` is created. This .git folder contains all the information that is necessary for your project regarding git (commits, remote repositories, etc). When you copy your project folder to move to your laptop B, be sure you copy all the folders and files (even the hidden) and specially the `.git` folder. This method should preserve your git history.

If you have problems with git credentials in your laptop B, you can delete the .git folder and start a new git local repo with `git init`, but this option will remove the previous git history.